# get and show 5 published post and show in diffrent div one by one wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I want to show first published post to in one single div and show second published post in second single div far my 5 recently published post. How should get each published post one by one and show it in different place in page?

According to codex, but can't grab specific post

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: you have use again same code to show different div

Comment: i konw, but i want get third or maybe second published post  and show it again in a seprated div i dont know how to do that

Comment: actuly im bulding a slide show and im trying  to show first published post in first slide and second published post in second  faaaaar slide5

Comment: use offset in your args array

    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'offset' => 5 );

Comment: @zyrag it will return 5 recent post side by side , i just want one post from 5 post for example  just show post 3 from entire 5 post

Comment: first of all do you need to access 1st and the 2nd posts always or are you going to select 2 posts out of 5 randomly ?

Comment: always need each 5 recent published post  it may come from difreent category .  i  need first div always show first published post .. second div always show second published post third div show third published post .. far 5 post

Answer (score 0):

Not a good solution but this may solve your problem

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

        echo '<li class="post".$i><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    $i++;
    }

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Then U will have post0,post1,2,3,4 classes you can reach all of these classes from CSS but repeating again This is not a good solution.

Comment: this code skip first post then show other posts back togeter , i cant choose specific post directly for example third post